# How to check if gridview has been tampered

Tags: asp.net

I am running some scan testing on an asp.net website.  The scanner is changing some of the data on the gridview such as follows:

```
Parameter  GridCustom$ctl10$CHK_SelRcd  manipulated from: on to: d4R4rs
```

As you can see a checkbox inside the grid GridCustom called "CHK_SelRcd" was modified and the grid did not detect this.  Is there some type of command similar to:

```
GridCustom.IsValid()
```

That I can check if the controls have been tampered with (Or have invalid values such as above checkbox)

Thank You

Comment: only on post back you can check it - actually on post back if a value for post back change your page will throw error

Comment: Correct the check will be on postback.  And no, the values were tampered and the gridview did not throw any errors.

Comment: Can you give a small example ?

Comment: No I cannot. You would need to have security scanning software.  If you would like to reproduce the error, you can take a look at the parameter I placed above.  It is a checkbox inside the gridview.  You would then need to modify the checkbox value ( GridCustom$ctl10$CHK_SelRcd) to a non-conforming value that is not "on".  For example as given above, you modify the parameter returned to the server (Post) to "d4R4rs" for the checkbox instead of "on".  The value is no longer valid but asp.net still accepts it.  I am looking to validate the grid, for example: "GridCustom.IsValid()"

Comment: need more checks and real example on that - I will make some test my self and probably come back -

Answer (score 1):

I make a very small example using a DropDownList - and a post back.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlTest">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**I change the Value** of one **using the inspect tools** of the browser and here is the message I got.

> **Invalid postback or callback argument**.  Event validation is enabled
> using  in configuration or <%@
> Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security
> purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
> events originate from the server control that originally rendered
> them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
> ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
> register the postback or callback data for validation.

Now there are parameters that even you can change it **are not affect the results on code behind**

### for example

1. If you change the `id`, the post back send the `name` - so no affect there.
2. If you change the `name` again the post back is not affected because this is go to a parameter that not exists
3. If you replace two `names` each other its again finds it and throw an error.